# How can I check if the FPGA device is connected to the server?

Tags: linux, opencl, fpga, intel-fpga

For some reason, I can only remotely control a server containing FPGA (Intel Arria 10 GX FPGA). But when I use the command in *Intel OpenCL for FPGA* to find the driver, I cannot find the FPGA device that can be used.
The command is as follows:
`aocl diagnose`
Output result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i206W.png)

Later, I used *hardinfo* to check whether FPGA is included, but unfortunately there is no useful information.

The only thing related to FPGA is that I found two files about fpga under my server (Ubuntu16.04). Since I am using FPGA for the first time, I don't know what this file represents.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NfDk.png)

In addition, due to network problems, I have not yet been able to install OPAE for testing. I would like to ask if there is an easy way to verify whether the FPGA is successfully inserted into the server.

Comment: Supplement: I have downloaded the corresponding FPGA device driver.

Comment: This is not a programming question. You could look through the links listed below to find an appropriate site.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I am asking a question here for the first time. I understand what you mean, but I think someone has already given a reply. If you think I don't need to delete the question, I will pay attention next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check with `lspci | grep "FPGA"`. The `lspci` command lists all devices connected to a PCIe slot, whether a driver is installed or not. If you find the FPGA in the list of devices, it is installed in the PCIe slot on the mainboard.

Comment: oh thanks, I just tried this but find nothing. I think maybe the FPGA isn't installed in the correct position.